# JQuery Onclick event.target Returning Wrong Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclicklistener

I'm trying to print the id of the target that I click on with the class `piece`. Here's the JavaScript.

```
function attachClickHandlers() {
  $('.piece').click(function(event) {
    console.log(event.target.id)
  })
}

attachClickHandlers();
```

HTML:

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="full-board">
      <div id="pieces">
        <img src="assets/w_r.svg" id="w_r1" class="piece">
        <img src="assets/w_n.svg" id="w_n1" class="piece">
        <img src="assets/w_b.svg" id="w_b1" class="piece">
        <img src="assets/w_q.svg" id="w_q" class="piece">
        <img src="assets/w_k.svg" id="w_k" class="piece">
        <img src="assets/w_b.svg" id="w_b2" class="piece">
        <img src="assets/w_n.svg" id="w_n2" class="piece">
        <img src="assets/w_r.svg" id="w_r2" class="piece">

        <img src="assets/w_p.svg" id="w_p1" class="piece">
        <img src="assets/w_p.svg" id="w_p2" class="piece">
        <img src="assets/w_p.svg" id="w_p3" class="piece">
        <img src="assets/w_p.svg" id="w_p4" class="piece">
        <img src="assets/w_p.svg" id="w_p5" class="piece">
        <img src="assets/w_p.svg" id="w_p6" class="piece">
        <img src="assets/w_p.svg" id="w_p7" class="piece">
        <img src="assets/w_p.svg" id="w_p8" class="piece">

        <img src="assets/b_r.svg" id="b_r1" class="piece">
        <img src="assets/b_n.svg" id="b_n1" class="piece">
        <img src="assets/b_b.svg" id="b_b1" class="piece">
        <img src="assets/b_q.svg" id="b_q" class="piece">
        <img src="assets/b_k.svg" id="b_k" class="piece">
        <img src="assets/b_b.svg" id="b_b2" class="piece">
        <img src="assets/b_n.svg" id="b_n2" class="piece">
        <img src="assets/b_r.svg" id="b_r2" class="piece">

        <img src="assets/b_p.svg" id="b_p1" class="piece">
        <img src="assets/b_p.svg" id="b_p2" class="piece">
        <img src="assets/b_p.svg" id="b_p3" class="piece">
        <img src="assets/b_p.svg" id="b_p4" class="piece">
        <img src="assets/b_p.svg" id="b_p5" class="piece">
        <img src="assets/b_p.svg" id="b_p6" class="piece">
        <img src="assets/b_p.svg" id="b_p7" class="piece">
        <img src="assets/b_p.svg" id="b_p8" class="piece">
      </div>
```

[image: What the website looks like on my browser]
However, if I click on any of the white pieces on the first row (pawns), it prints `w_p8` and if I click on any of the white pieces on the second row, it prints `w_r2`.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: It worked for most of you that tried it so it's probably something else in my code. Sorry I didn't include it at the beginning, I didn't think anything else would have much of an effect I managed to reproduce the problem here on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/chy86fbq/

Comment: I tried with the exactly same code with a jsfiddle, and it works. Don't know if it's related, but you've got a missing </div> at the end

Comment: Works fine with your example

Comment: It is working as intended.

Comment: @KCarnaille thanks for letting me know (I missed it when copy pasting)

Comment: This doesn't work when I test it... what should I do next? Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said:

> I'm trying to print the id of the target that I click on with the
> class "piece" whose name also includes "w".

Probably instead of name you mean `id`. so you need to check if the id `includes` `w` or not then log it. Also note that you've missed a closing `div` tag.

**Update**

Based on your comment related to share your whole code (https://jsfiddle.net/chy86fbq/), you are using `position = 'absolute'` and don't set `left` and `top`. Instead of setting `paddingLeft` and `paddingTop` you need to set `left` and `top` for `piece` class.

```js
   console.clear();
   attachClickHandlers();
        function attachClickHandlers() {
            $('.piece').click(function (event) {
                if (event.target.id.includes("w"))
                    console.log(event.target.id)
            })
        }
```

```css
 img {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            outline: 1px solid black;
        }
```

```html
       <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
   <div id="full-board">
        <div id="pieces">
            <img src="assets/w_r.svg" alt="w_r1" id="w_r1" class="piece">
            <img src="assets/w_n.svg" alt="w_n1" id="w_n1" class="piece">
            <img src="assets/w_b.svg" alt="w_b1" id="w_b1" class="piece">
            <img src="assets/w_q.svg" alt="w_q" id="w_q" class="piece">
            <img src="assets/w_k.svg" alt="w_k" id="w_k" class="piece">
            <img src="assets/w_b.svg" alt="w_b2" id="w_b2" class="piece">
            <img src="assets/w_n.svg" alt="w_n2" id="w_n2" class="piece">
            <img src="assets/w_r.svg" alt="w_r2" id="w_r2" class="piece">

            <img src="assets/w_p.svg" alt="w_p1" id="w_p1" class="piece">
            <img src="assets/w_p.svg" alt="w_p2" id="w_p2" class="piece">
            <img src="assets/w_p.svg" alt="w_p3" id="w_p3" class="piece">
            <img src="assets/w_p.svg" alt="w_p4" id="w_p4" class="piece">
            <img src="assets/w_p.svg" alt="w_p5" id="w_p5" class="piece">
            <img src="assets/w_p.svg" alt="w_p6" id="w_p6" class="piece">
            <img src="assets/w_p.svg" alt="w_p7" id="w_p7" class="piece">
            <img src="assets/w_p.svg" alt="w_p8" id="w_p8" class="piece">

            <img src="assets/b_r.svg" alt="b_r1" id="b_r1" class="piece">
            <img src="assets/b_n.svg" alt="b_n1" id="b_n1" class="piece">
            <img src="assets/b_b.svg" alt="b_b1" id="b_b1" class="piece">
            <img src="assets/b_q.svg" alt="b_q" id="b_q" class="piece">
            <img src="assets/b_k.svg" alt="b_k" id="b_k" class="piece">
            <img src="assets/b_b.svg" alt="b_b2" id="b_b2" class="piece">
            <img src="assets/b_n.svg" alt="b_n2" id="b_n2" class="piece">
            <img src="assets/b_r.svg" alt="b_r2" id="b_r2" class="piece">

            <img src="assets/b_p.svg" alt="b_p1" id="b_p1" class="piece">
            <img src="assets/b_p.svg" alt="b_p2" id="b_p2" class="piece">
            <img src="assets/b_p.svg" alt="b_p3" id="b_p3" class="piece">
            <img src="assets/b_p.svg" alt="b_p4" id="b_p4" class="piece">
            <img src="assets/b_p.svg" alt="b_p5" id="b_p5" class="piece">
            <img src="assets/b_p.svg" alt="b_p6" id="b_p6" class="piece">
            <img src="assets/b_p.svg" alt="b_p7" id="b_p7" class="piece">
            <img src="assets/b_p.svg" alt="b_p8" id="b_p8" class="piece">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yep, I meant the id! It still only prints "w_p8" on my browser though... can you point me in the right direction? I'm guessing now that it's probably to do with the way Chrome is configured or something?

Comment: No I don't think depends on chrome configuration. I made a working snippet for you. compare my snippet with your code. Or Copy and paste my html into your code

Comment: I copy pasted the html into my code... still outputs `w_p8`. Your snippet does work though.

Comment: I'm not really comfortable with that, sorry. Could you tell me what you'd be looking into/looking for?

Comment: Managed to reproduce it here https://jsfiddle.net/8xd874q9/4/

Comment: Yep, I did put it there.

Comment: I see only three button!! put your whole code.

Comment: I'm so sorry!! I linked the wrong one. Here's the right one: https://jsfiddle.net/chy86fbq/

Comment: I've got the problem. It is because of `position:absolute` in `setPiecePosition` methods. https://jsfiddle.net/xsv2aeow/2/

Comment: Do you know why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234963/discussion-between-alireza-ahmadi-and-ariel).

Answer (score 0):

function `attachClickHandlers` need to initialize  in `document.ready`, and check for `w`,please follow the below code

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
   <div id="full-board">
      <div id="pieces">
         <img src="assets/w_r.svg" id="w_r1" class="piece">
         <img src="assets/w_n.svg" id="w_n1" class="piece">
         <img src="assets/w_b.svg" id="w_b1" class="piece">
         <img src="assets/w_q.svg" id="w_q" class="piece">
         <img src="assets/w_k.svg" id="w_k" class="piece">
         <img src="assets/w_b.svg" id="w_b2" class="piece">
         <img src="assets/w_n.svg" id="w_n2" class="piece">
         <img src="assets/w_r.svg" id="w_r2" class="piece">
         <img src="assets/w_p.svg" id="w_p1" class="piece">
         <img src="assets/w_p.svg" id="w_p2" class="piece">
         <img src="assets/w_p.svg" id="w_p3" class="piece">
         <img src="assets/w_p.svg" id="w_p4" class="piece">
         <img src="assets/w_p.svg" id="w_p5" class="piece">
         <img src="assets/w_p.svg" id="w_p6" class="piece">
         <img src="assets/w_p.svg" id="w_p7" class="piece">
         <img src="assets/w_p.svg" id="w_p8" class="piece">
         <img src="assets/b_r.svg" id="b_r1" class="piece">
         <img src="assets/b_n.svg" id="b_n1" class="piece">
         <img src="assets/b_b.svg" id="b_b1" class="piece">
         <img src="assets/b_q.svg" id="b_q" class="piece">
         <img src="assets/b_k.svg" id="b_k" class="piece">
         <img src="assets/b_b.svg" id="b_b2" class="piece">
         <img src="assets/b_n.svg" id="b_n2" class="piece">
         <img src="assets/b_r.svg" id="b_r2" class="piece">
         <img src="assets/b_p.svg" id="b_p1" class="piece">
         <img src="assets/b_p.svg" id="b_p2" class="piece">
         <img src="assets/b_p.svg" id="b_p3" class="piece">
         <img src="assets/b_p.svg" id="b_p4" class="piece">
         <img src="assets/b_p.svg" id="b_p5" class="piece">
         <img src="assets/b_p.svg" id="b_p6" class="piece">
         <img src="assets/b_p.svg" id="b_p7" class="piece">
         <img src="assets/b_p.svg" id="b_p8" class="piece">
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
<script>
   function attachClickHandlers() {
             $('.piece').click(function(event) {
   
              console.log("event.target.id.includes('w')" +event.target.id.includes("w"));
   console.log("event.target.id" +event.target.id);
          });
          }
            $( document ).ready(function() {
     attachClickHandlers();
   });
       
</script>
```

Refer - https://api.jquery.com/ready/ , https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/   ,  https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp

Regards
DK

Comment: I tried this, and it still outputs "w_p8".

Answer (score 0):

I struggled for three hours to find a solution, I was using the class name to catch the event, but once I give every element diffrent `id` now the event `$(this)` pointed to the correct element clicked.